# Changing My Default Login

Tags: 2010, office

I currently work with two accounts MyUserName and an admin account MyAdminName. I've use MyAdminName quite extensively but now I'm trying to make a habit of using MyUserName as my default account.

Currently when I open SharePoint in a browser it will default to MyAdminName by default even though I'm logged into my workstation with MyUserName account. I can log in as a different user as long as I notice. Another issue is when I open any document directly from MS Word or MS Excel it saves the document using MyAdminName instead of MyUserName and I don't know how to change that.

Is there any way to change this default behavior? I'm working in SharePoint 2010, Office 2010 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely you have at some point saved your admin credentials to the domain of your SharePoint site.  Check the [Credential Manager](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/manage-network-logon-credentials-in-microsoft-windows/) and clear out your admin credentials.  If you have mapped a network drive to your SharePoint site then that would also cause this behavior and you need to disconnect the mapped drive.

Windows has a habit of caching credentials within a session even after you change them so you might need to reboot after making the changes.